# Passing wrong ref to Array VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, string, variables

I have had help putting this together, can someone explain why i'm passing the wrong information to the Array, I assume its because the Array is a Variant currently and not a string.  Do i have to change the function or do i change the variable from a variant to a string, if so how?  many thanks.

```
    Function CountString(FullString As String, PartialString As String) As Long
         CountString = UBound(Split(FullString, PartialString))
    End Function 

    Dim ws2 As Worksheet, rng As Range, totcount As Long, cell As Range, strsearch1 As Variant
    
    strsearch1 = Array("Cat", "Dog")
    
    For Each ws2 In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
     If (ws2.Name) <> "Search Results" Then
       ws2.Activate
       ActiveSheet.Columns("H:H").EntireColumn.Delete
       ActiveSheet.Columns("H:H").NumberFormat = "0"
       ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
    
       Set rng = ws2.Range("C2:D10")
       For Each cell In rng
           cell.Select
           totcount = "0"
           totcount = totcount + CountString(cell.Value, strsearch1)
   
           Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Select
           ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Select
           ActiveCell = ActiveCell.Value + totcount
   
       Next cell
     End If
   Next ws2
```

Comment: That code shouldn't work - the function ends on row 4, the rest of the code isn't sitting within a function or procedure.

Comment: Did you only copy here your code, in this way? I mean,  everything starting from `Dim ws2 As Worksheet` up to `Next ws2` must be inside of a `Sub`. And the function (I made it for you), does not need the second line. The person who said that in his case it returned one more, admitted that he was making a mistake... In fact, I will edit your question in this regards. Besides all that, no need to select anything.

Comment: I did add some more lines to move to a column add the information to a cell, which all seems to work but i tried to change it so that i could use multiple terms which eventually will be linked to a textbox, but its at that time i screwed it up.

Comment: And thank you for your patience, both of you i know it seems simple to you guys, but for me not so much :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking your code should look like this:

```
Sub Test1()

    Dim ws2 As Worksheet, rng As Range, totcount As Long, cell As Range, strsearch1 As Variant
    Dim itm As Variant

    strsearch1 = Array("Cat", "Dog")

    For Each ws2 In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws2.Name <> "Search Results" Then
            ws2.Columns("H:H").EntireColumn.Delete
            ws2.Columns("H:H").NumberFormat = "0"
            
            Set rng = ws2.Range("C2:D10")
            For Each cell In rng
                totcount = 0
                
                'Pass each item in the array to the function, 'Cstr' converts it to a string first.
                For Each itm In strsearch1
                    totcount = totcount + CountString(cell.Value, CStr(itm))
                    cell.Offset(0, 7) = cell.Offset(0, 7) + totcount
                Next itm
            Next cell
            
        End If
    Next ws2

End Sub
```

I don't understand want your code should be doing though.

Does `UBOUND(Split("x","x"))` ever return anything except 1?  It splits the string `x` by the delimiter `x` which will give two empty strings in an array - the `LBOUND` of this will be 0, the `UBOUND` will be 1.